# What is the encoding of the data attribute in the new Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

The new Google Maps have URLs that look like this:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/coffee/@37.0625,-95.677068,4z/data=!3m1!4b1
```

Obviously the search term is "coffee" and `@37.0625,-95.677068,4z` is the lat, lng and zoom; but what is data? I.e. what encoding is `!3m1!4b1`?

Comment: Check out article about the url format of the new google maps: http://moz.com/blog/new-google-maps-url-parameters

Comment: Thanks for this link! It definitely shines some light on the issue, but ti still doesn't answer what is this for encoding. In the background gmaps is sending hundreds of requests like this:
https://www.google.com/maps/vt/pb=!1m4!1m3!1i2!2i0!3i1!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i267096279!3m4!2sen!5e1105!12m1!1e47!4e1!5m4!1e4!8m2!1e0!1e1!6m15!1e3!2i11!16e1!19m4!1e1!2e0!4m1!1e0!20m4!1e1!2e3!3m1!1e0!30m1!1f1.1320754289627075!7s!20m1!1b1
and I really would like to know what it is all supposed to mean.

Comment: It is protobuf according to [this blog post](https://medium.com/@marin_m/how-i-found-a-5-000-google-maps-xss-by-fiddling-with-protobuf-963ee0d9caff) which goes far to decypher and manipulate it.

Answer (score 32):

I've never seen this encoding, I guess it's something proprietary by Google. There are some hints about the structure though. I clicked on "embed" and got a longer url, with the same syntax:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m12!1m8!1m3!1d26081603.294420473!2d-95.677068!3d37.0625!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!2m1!1scoffee!5e0!3m2!1sde!2s!4v1404930797899" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

The `!` char is quite likely a separator. For better readability, some line breaks:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=
!1m12
!1m8
!1m3
!1d26081603.294420473
!2d-95.677068
!3d37.0625
!3m2
!1i1024
!2i768
!4f13.1
!2m1
!1scoffee
!5e0
!3m2
!1sde
!2s
!4v1404930797899
```

The pattern seems to be `!<id><data type><value>`.
Some of the data types we see here:  `s` is a string, `b` is boolean, `i` is integer, `d` is double, `f` float.

Now this is just a guess, but I think `m` is a container and there is the pattern that `!<id>m<X>` is followed by `X` parameters. This way similiar values are grouped, the IDs are unique and in ascending order on each level:

```
!1m12
  !1m8
    !1m3
      !1d26081603.294420473
      !2d-95.677068
      !3d37.0625
    !3m2
      !1i1024
      !2i768
    !4f13.1
  !2m1
    !1scoffee
  !5e0
!3m2
  !1sde
  !2s
!4v1404930797899
```

Another example, after clicking on a random coffee shop. I've tried to identify some of the values.

```
!1m14
  !1m8
    !1m3
      !1d3101.011519367493   // zoom level
      !2d-94.59454913903049  // longitude
      !3d38.99223345944582   // latitude
    !3m2
      !1i1024                // looks like some screen resolution,
      !2i768                 // but never changes
    !4f13.1
  !3m3
    !1m2
      !1s0x0%3A0xaf8a57446f312899
      !2sOne+More+Cup        // business name that I clicked
  !5e0
!3m2
  !1sde                      // language (german)
  !2s
!4v1404933052643             // timestamp
```

So if this is somewhat right, your example `!3m1!4b1` is a boolean value.

Comment: I created a basic Javascript Gist based on your answer to parse the "data" attribute value into an `Array`: https://gist.github.com/jeteon/e71fa21c1feb48fe4b5eeec045229a0c

Comment: What about this place, how do you get the GPS coordinates for it?
`https://www.google.com/maps/place/@/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x88c2cdd22ab04385:0xf12ec367be629fbc`

Comment: @TruthSeeker I think that URL only contains the ID of the place but not the actual coordinates. After loading the map, the URL actually changes for me after a few seconds and then the new URL contains the coordinates.

Comment: @kapex, I found out there is an undocumented API to convert the hexadecimal values check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017387/decoding-the-google-maps-embedded-parameters

Comment: Is true that 2d and 3d are longitude and latitude, but not from the location we want but for calculating de positioning of the map.

Comment: What is `!5e0` stands for?

Comment: @Sisir Maybe 'e' stands for 'enum' and the '0' is the enum value? But that's really just a guess. It's hard to tell what its for

Answer (score 1):

- !1s....!2e0 - panorama ID
- !1s....!2e10 - photo ID of the panorama, cannot be used to obtain panorama via API

My article on how to retrieve the location and panorama ID from various types of Google Maps shared links:

https://github.com/asilichenko/streetview-vr-walker/wiki/Extracting-Panorama-ID-and-Location-from-the-Google-Maps-Link

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).

Answer (score 0):

### I found out a little bit more:

==> !4m4
Display the Street View panorama ....

...in the same mode as the map. In this case, the map is in entry mode, so the Street View panorama will also be in entry mode.

...at the same zoom level as the map. In this case, the map is zoomed in to the closest entry point, so the Street View panorama will also be zoomed in to the closest entry point.

### ...at the same latitude and longitude as the map.

==> !3m1!1e3
View setting Aerial

### ... This parameter tells Google Maps to display the Street View panorama with a heading of 0 degrees. A heading of 0 degrees means that the Street View panorama is facing north.

(Sorry for the font....I do not know how to correct that. I'm pretty new to posting here)

Comment: Answer is not well formatted.