# Add avoid highway to maps url

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-urls

I am working on a JavaScript project aimed at creating a route while considering stops at electric vehicle charging stations. Once the route is ready, the user can click on a button that redirects this route to Google Maps. Here's how I do it.

```js
document.getElementById('openMapBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var googleMapsLink = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/";

  // Ajouter l'origine
  googleMapsLink += encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("from").value);

  // Ajouter les étapes intermédiaires
  infosBornes.forEach(function(borne) {
    googleMapsLink += "/" + encodeURIComponent(borne.adresse);
  });

  // Ajouter la destination
  googleMapsLink += "/" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("to").value);

  // Vérifier si l'utilisateur veut éviter les autoroutes
  var avoidHighwaysStatut = document.getElementById('avoidHighways');
  if (avoidHighwaysStatut.checked) {
    googleMapsLink += "/&dirflg=h,t";
  }

  // Ouvrir le lien dans une nouvelle fenêtre
  window.open(googleMapsLink);
});
```

The problem is here

```js
if (avoidHighwaysStatut.checked) {
    googleMapsLink += "/&dirflg=h,t"; 
  }
```

How to fix this error and avoid highWay :/ Thank's !

Comment: What error are you getting?  Check the developer tools console.

Comment: There's no error, maps recreates the URL, removes the parameters and as a result, I have the highways.

Comment: What URL? I don't see any URL in your code / question.

Answer (score 1):

First, as mentioned in the [google map direction URL documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action), the query parameter `?api=1` is required. If it is missing, all parameters will be removed. You are missing that. Also, the origin and destination needs to be specified using query parameters as well. For example:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=/NC+State+University+NC&destination=Burlington+NC

However, in the official doc there is no parameter that specifies avoiding highway, hence one hacky option is to use the undocumented `maps/dir/{origin}/{destination}/data` url, following with a bunch of parameters separated by `!`. In your case, you'll need `data=!4m3!4m2!2m1!1b1`.

There is a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809103/what-is-the-encoding-of-the-data-attribute-in-the-new-google-maps) about the observations that people have made about these parameters. In your example, in each of the parameters, the first number is the parameter ID, and the second character is the parameter type. `m` means it's a container that nests parameters, and `b` means bool. The third number's meaning depends on the parameter type. For `m` it indicates how many parameters are grouped under this container. `1b1` is the no highway option, and it is under containers `4m->4m->2m`, resulting `!4m3!4m2!2m1!1b1`.

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/NC+State+University+NC/Burlington+NC/data=!4m3!4m2!2m1!1b1

---

**Edit**

Just found a really [complete article](https://mstickles.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/gmaps-urls-options/) that documents the observations of these *undocumented* parameters. The above explanation matches it as well.

However, as mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78122174/add-avoid-highway-to-maps-url/78122609#comment137727092_78122609), one must keep in mind that this is undocumented which means it's subject to be changed anytime without notice. If creating a Map ID is feasible (might be free or billed depends on your use case), the better options is to use the [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview), which includes the [avoidHighways option](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests).

Comment: yes is this thank's !

Comment: Not sure OP even checked the Maps URLs documentation and you are right that this is what one should use to build Google Maps URLs. That said, the last part of your answer is **undocumented** which means that these parameters are subject to change at any time without notice, which could break your implementation. Instead of using undocumented parameters, you should open a feature request in their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/578484) and ask for that parameter to be added.

Comment: Another solution : use the Maps Javascript API or the Maps Embed API which both have that option available when requesting directions.

Comment: yes I agree, I was planning to add that warning in the answer but I've forgot :\

Answer (score -1):

My apologies, I found the solution, here it is.

```js
if (avoidHighwaysStatut.checked) {
    googleMapsLink += "/data=!4m3!4m2!2m1!2b1"; 
    }
```

Comment: `2b1` is to avoid toll roads, not highway from what I've seen.

Comment: in france it's the same thing

Comment: @bryanmottais no it isn't. Highways are considered toll roads, that is true. But some non-highway roads can also be toll roads. Think about some tunnels, bridges, etc.